# Reduce Mobile Image upload size (wordpress)

Tags: images, uploads, mobile

Just a quick question about mobile image upload size.

I am using WP user frontend pro to upload images from both desktop and mobile.

Using the mobile when the "image" button is tapped, an user can take a photo which gets uploaded.

However the size of the image is about 3 MB which is totally overkill.

I contacted the plugin developer to see how I can compress the size of the image before uploading it so that it doesn't take too long to upload it but they said they will work on it for their future update which could be a long wait.

I was just wondering if you guys have any ideas to how I can reduce the size of the image even before being uploaded? or compress it. You know what i mean =)

Anyway, any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: yes, I have an idea, but this is not wordpress specific question.... You can manipulate the image on the front-end with the canvas API.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. Would you happen to know how to include canvas API to wordpress?

Comment: canvas API is part of the DOM API, there is nothing that needs to be "included" for it.

Comment: Sorry for not fully understanding how to do it (new at this). So let say I have this page (http://realmonster.ca/add/) which has the image upload button. When a new photo is taken, it shows that the size is 2.8MB. How would I implement this API so that the size is compressed for faster uploading?

Comment: Actually I found this which might be the right approach : http://www.plupload.com/docs/Image-Resizing-on-Client-Side